# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs', tried try-except method

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to fetch Instagram account details.
Tried using `try/except`, but the problem persists.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/{}/'
def scrap_data(user_name):
    data = requests.get(URL.format(user_name))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
    meta = soup.find('meta', property='og:description')
    s = meta.attrs['Content']
    s = s.split('_')[0]
    print(s)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_name = input("Enter instagram username:")
    scrap_data(user_name)
```

Comment: instagram create dynamic content using javascript and BeautifulSoup may not work you can try selenium.

Comment: In the line that you are trying to find 'meta' tags and put them in the meta variable, the soup does not find any meta tag, so meta variable would be empty or None.
This problem occurs because you are browsing a wrong url. My suggestion is to open the url at first in your browser and make sure that there is meta tags in it, then edit your code.

Answer (score 1):

I run your script to request this account: https://www.instagram.com/dubaksk/
and when I print response data:

```
URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/{}/'
def scrap_data(user_name):
    data = requests.get(URL.format(user_name))
    print(data.text)
```

I see:

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in ">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Page Not Found &bull; Instagram</title>        
        <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex, noarchive">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/data/manifest.json">
```

So the response does not contain `meta` tag `og:description`. It is actually saying `Page Not Found` and response `status_code` is 429: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429

I am suspecting there is some scraping protection by Instagram. Checking the incoming requests headers. If they see some generic headers generated by requests library, they just deny the request.

You will have to investigate why more deeply by setting custom headers being sent to Instagram.